# Help understanding schematic (voltage regulator)

Tags: power-supply, transistors, ac, dc, switch-mode-power-supply

I got this voltage regulator that I wanted to use with a DC source (30V switching power supply from a printer). [image]
(full schematic [here](https://img.banggood.com/file/products/201505080459530-30Vinstall.pdf) )

However, I see that input of the voltage regulator MUST be powered from an AC source (transformer). I think it uses a trick to obtain dual voltage for the op amps.
1. Is this correct?
2. How do I modify the schematic so that it will work with DC input?

Comment: What is output rating for this regulator? Volts? Amps?

Comment: Looks like they added a weak \$-5\:\textrm{V}\$ rail using that "trick" you mentioned. (To "help" the opamps have a larger output range.) Also, you need to be aware that a \$90\:\textrm{W}\$, \$24\:\textrm{V}_\textrm{AC}\$ transformer may supply a positive voltage rail that may be somewhat more than just \$30\: \textrm{V}_\textrm{DC}\$. As the doc says, you can't just plug DC to the input. You either must ignore (get rid of) or else construct separately a low current negative rail.

Comment: @AliChen They allow up to \$3\:\textrm{A}\$ for the output current limit. So that's the amps. The output voltage can be up to \$30\:\textrm{V}\$ they say.

Comment: @jonk, my bad, I missed the link. What I was fishing for is that the cost of making a negative rail charge pump could be more than the entire board. Now I see that this seems to be a full-featured CV/CC supply, a reasonable benchtop PSU substitute, so it might make sense to add a negative mirror from the 30 V DC input to make the negative rail for OPAmps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R2, C2, D5, D6, C3, R3. ZD7 is a capacitive dropper type PSU for negative voltage used in op amps. You can place a small DC/DC converter in its place. The main information comes from zener diode, this is the negative voltage value to meet.

Although, it is not clearly why this power supply needs the negative voltage, perhaps some old op amps can't go such low. Imo if you don't need very low voltage to be set on this bench PSU you can get rid of the negative PSU. In such case the resistor R14 has to be changed. Perhaps also changing U3 and U2 with a modern rail to rail op amp won't make much difference even without the negative PSU.

EDIT:

The U3 and U2 are more likely comparators rather than op amps.

EDIT2:

R13 and R14 form a voltage divider. The input voltage 24AC is rectified and you get somewhere around 32VDC. The base-emitter voltage of Q1 gets -0.2V, which means the transistor is in off conduction. Rising the input voltage above certain level the Vbe of Q1 will reach 0.65V and the Q1 will start conduct, thus shutting down the output voltage of the output of the PSU. Kind of input overvoltage protection circuit. You can eliminate the Q1 - not mounted. Then you eliminate the -5V PSU as well. You won't be able to set the output voltage level near 0V, also you won't be able to set the current level at 3mA, only.

Do not mount components: R2, C2, D5, D6, C3, R3. ZD7, Q1. In place of zener diode ZD7 put a jumper (short = 0 ohm). Test and see, if you are not satisfied, buy a transformer 24VAC.

Comment: All three opamps are TL081 (JFet input.)

Comment: I don't think the OP is in the position to re-design the product under your suggestion. Having the current sense circuitry to work down to 3 mA would require some effort with single-rails OPAmps.

Comment: "You won't be able to set the output voltage level near 0V" - that's fine. It is ok if I can vary the output voltage in the 3V-30V range.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the trick.  It is called a charge pump, and does require an oscillating input.  To get around this, one approach is to use a resistor and zener to make a small 9 V source to power a 555 oscillator.  The 555 drives the charge pump in the schematic starting at R2.

Answer (score 1):

There are charge pump ICs designed to work with DC, such as MAX660. To get -5V, you can generate +5V by whatever means you have available (Zener diode, 7805 or a full-blown buck converter), then use the following schematic to invert it:

[image]

Exclude R2, C2, D5, D6, C3, R3, D7 from your initial schematic, and connect Vin to a +5V source and -Vin to the -5V rail (supplying the opamps and R14). Don't forget to connect the ground as well.